# .Net library for saving an image to Mac's PICT/PCT file format

Tags: c#, image, macos

Does anyone know of a .Net library for saving or converting an image to the Mac PCT/PICT file format?

I can save a JPG to PCT/PICT format in Photoshop; and I see this LeadTools library for $995 dollars, but would like to spend less money than that for the simple convert. I don't need all the other features this costly library supports. http://www.leadtools.com/SDK/Raster/Formats/Raster-Format-MACPICT.htm

A client claims that need JPG images saved in PIC/PICT file format for their SASI yearbook Mac software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other than writing your own exporter, you may be able to use [ImageMagick's QuickDraw PICT support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).

I have seen their [API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) used successfully from P/Invoke and COM; there is an [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx) I just found that uses it from VB.NET.

If it helps, here is [the file format for PICT](http://www.fileformat.info/format/macpict/egff.htm). PICT v1.0 is substantially out of date (I believe it was deprecated sometime in the 90s). Inside Macintosh also has some details on the PICT v2.0 format, and I seem to remember hearing something about JPEG encoding in PICT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.imagemagick.org/

It is a C++ lib, but they have .NET wrapper
[ImageMagicNET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx)